# List in the function exponent meaning

Tags: exponentiation

I get a weird exponential inside the function that appears as the result of an integral in Mathematica. Namely, the function

$Hypergeometric1F1^{(1,0,0)}[1, 1, -x^2]$

has the 3-component list in the exponential. I have searched everywhere to find the explanation of the $(1,0,0)$ exponent, but couldn't find it. Does anyone know its meaning?

It seems that number of terms in the exponent must match the number of arguments.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{Hypergeometric1F1}^{(1,0,0)}[1, 1, -x^2]\;$ is the partial derivative of $\;{}_1F_1(x_1;x_2;x_3)\,$ relatively to the first parameter :
$\quad\displaystyle\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}\; {}_1F_1(x_1;x_2;x_3)\;$ taken at $\;x_1=1,\,x_2=1,\,x_3=-x^2$.

$\operatorname{Hypergeometric1F1}^{(0,2,0)}[1, 1, -x^2]\;$ means $\;\;\left.\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial (x_2)^2}\;{}_1F_1(x_1;x_2;x_3)\right|_{x_1=1,\,x_2=1,\,x_3=-x^2}$

and so on...

The same notation is used for other multi-parameters functions.

Wolfram's Derivative operator $D$ is described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheRepresentationOfDerivatives.html) with some examples including :

Input : $\quad D[g[x, y], y]$
Output : $\quad g^{(0,1)}[x,y]$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Couldn't find it anywhere really.

Comment: Glad it helped @Mihailo! This rather convenient notation was probably inspired by the classical $\;f^{(1)}(x)=f'(x),\;f^{(2)}(x)=f''(x),\cdots\,$ which can be generalized to multiple integrals as in this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042798001927) or even to [fractional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus). Excellent continuation,